# Go binary search error

Tags: search, go, binary-search

Suppose you have two use cases:

```
a := [] int {2, 2, 3, 4}
i := sort.Search(len(a), func(pos int) bool { return a[pos] == 2})
fmt.Printf("%v -> %v \n", a, i)

b := [] int {1, 2, 2, 3, 4}
j := sort.Search(len(b), func(pos int) bool { return b[pos] == 2})
fmt.Printf("%v -> %v \n", b, j)
```

Answer for those are:

```
[2 2 3 4] -> 4
[1 2 2 3 4] -> 1
```

I suppose it must be `1` in both cases, no? Does anyone knows why?

Answer (score 4):

[`sort.Search()`](https://golang.org/pkg/sort/#Search) returns the smallest index `i` in `[0, n)` at which `f(i)` is `true`.

Since slice indices are 0-based, you should expect a return of `0` for the first and `1` for the second. It (seemingly) works for the second.

Quoting from the doc:

> ...assuming that on the range [0, n), `f(i) == true` implies `f(i+1) == true`. That is, Search requires that `f` is `false` for some (possibly empty) prefix of the input range [0, n) and then `true` for the (possibly empty) remainder; Search returns the first `true` index. If there is no such index, Search returns `n`.

Your function does not meet the criteria `sort.Search()` expects. Your function is not to tell if the element at the specified index is the one you're looking for, but rather to tell:

- if the element at the requested index is **equal to or is greater than** (return `true`)
- or if the element at the specified index is **less than the searched one** (return `false`).

(A binary search could not be carried out if you would only tell when they are equal but not when they are greater or less.)

So simply use `>=` comparison instead of `==`. Correct usage:

```
a := []int{2, 2, 3, 4}
i := sort.Search(len(a), func(pos int) bool { return a[pos] >= 2 })
fmt.Printf("%v -> %v \n", a, i)

b := []int{1, 2, 2, 3, 4}
j := sort.Search(len(b), func(pos int) bool { return b[pos] >= 2 })
fmt.Printf("%v -> %v \n", b, j)
```

Output (try it on the <kbd>[Go Playground](http://play.golang.org/p/2Tf_lT03cQ)</kbd>):

```
[2 2 3 4] -> 0 
[1 2 2 3 4] -> 1
```

Note: also from the doc:

> For instance, given a slice data sorted in ascending order, the call
>
> ```
> Search(len(data), func(i int) bool { return data[i] >= 23 })
> ```
>
> returns the smallest index `i` such that `data[i] >= 23`. If the caller wants to find whether `23` is in the slice, it must test `data[i] == 23` separately.

### Easier alternative: `sort.SearchInts()`

If you want to search for an `int` value in an `int` slice (`[]int`), simply use [`sort.SearchInts()`](https://golang.org/pkg/sort/#SearchInts):

```
a := []int{2, 2, 3, 4}
i := sort.SearchInts(a, 2)
fmt.Printf("%v -> %v \n", a, i)

b := []int{1, 2, 2, 3, 4}
j := sort.SearchInts(b, 2)
fmt.Printf("%v -> %v \n", b, j)
```

Output (try it on the <kbd>[Go Playground](http://play.golang.org/p/DMS5nBQ2Wz)</kbd>):

```
[2 2 3 4] -> 0 
[1 2 2 3 4] -> 1
```